# how to debug vim config (.vimrc)

Tags: vim

I have a line

```
set cpoptions+=$  "add the '$' sign as change command indicator
```

in my .vimrc file, however after vim is started

```
set cpoptions?
```

shows the '$' option isn't set. if I type :set cpoptions+=$ manually in vim everything works fine.

I suspect during the vim initialization, after the line in my .vimrc file gets executed, the option somehow gets reset(could be a plugin).

my question is, does vim provide command/tool to debug issues like this?

I am using vim on Mac OS X (*NOT* MacVim).

Thanks!

-Xiaotian

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
:verbose set cpoptions?
```

will tell you where it was last set.

Comment: +1 because there's something new to be learned every day! Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: After 45 minutes of slogging through my vimrc file trying to figure out what in the world was screwing up my tabstop, I finally stumbled on your answer and found it instantly. Much thanks!